# ios 6 supportedInterfaceOrientations

Tags: xcode, uiview, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

In my apilicacion use the following method to rotate:

```
- (NSUInteger) {supportedInterfaceOrientations
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

But when load the next view

```
 View2 *Cambio =[[View2 alloc]initWithNibName:Nil bundle:Nil];
 Cambio.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
 [self presentViewController:Cambio animated:NO completion:^{/* done */}];
```

but this automatically rotated to `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight to UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```